# Bootstrap Modal opens automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dont know whats really happening, but i just implement modal (without the js call) and it opens automatically on page load.
I have two on the same page, does anybody knows why this is happening and how to make them to open only on the link?
thanks in advance

```
<a href="#save-list" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Title</a>
<div id="save-list" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-body">
<p><h4>sample text</h4></p>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12"><input name="" type="text"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
<button class="btn btn-confirm">Yes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And this one

```
<a href="#save-add-guest" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Popup de transición entre tabs</a>
<div id="save-add-guest" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-body">
<p><h4>Would you like to add these <br>contacts to the guest list?</h4></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No, Thanks</button>
<button class="btn btn-confirm">Yes Please!</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add functioning code with jsfiddle that will help us help you ...we need to see the js

Comment: the problem was with js, i was calling it through js and this mode is without js. my fault

Comment: yeah figures its the function.

Comment: @canute - please consider answering your own question to let everybody  here know it was solved.